# Snowflake SQL Query to extract codes from JSON data

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hope you are doing well!.. I am trying to extract the CPT and the ICD-10 codes from coded encounters..An encounter is denoted by the combination of ctextid and vbillid ..I want to extract the complexity value , under codes extract name and type and combine codes of a specific type by commas for one encounter (all present in the column data)...Please find the DDL below for the input and output tables...Can you please help me here..

```
**Input**

Create table ##input
(ctextid int,
vbillid int,
data variant)

insert into ##input values
('7812','1012','"{\"complexity\": \"low\", \"Codes\": [{\"conf\": 0.9940267346365206, \"name\": \"87635\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/li/dd\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"nasal passage)   RAPID SARS COV 2 AG, QL IA, RESPIRATORY SPECIMEN  Result:   -  Rapid Covid: positive Discussion Notes Discussed lab results.  Discussed need for isolation or quarantine.  Discussed need to supplement with:  Vitamin\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9991469971682254, \"name\": \"Z20828\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[3]/ul/li\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9969459941440534, \"name\": \"U071\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Assessment / Plan 1. COVID-19 U07.1: COVID-19  CORONAVIRUS (COVID-19): CARE INSTRUCTIONS\"}}], \"clinicalEncounterId\": 1535}"'),
('899','189','"{\"complexity\": \"low\", \"Codes\": [{\"conf\": 0.9944347091789092, \"name\": \"81002\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"irregular menstruation  US, TRANSVAGINAL 2. Vaginitis and vulvovaginitis N76.0: Acute vaginitis  URINALYSIS, DIPSTICK  VAGINITIS: CARE INSTRUCTIONS  URINALYSIS, DIPSTICK  Results:   -  Leukocytes: Negative  -  Nitrite: negative  -  Glucose:\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9999579891538954, \"name\": \"N760\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Assessment / Plan 1. Irregular periods N92.5: Other specified irregular menstruation  US, TRANSVAGINAL 2. Vaginitis and vulvovaginitis N76.0: Acute vaginitis  URINALYSIS, DIPSTICK  VAGINITIS: CARE INSTRUCTIONS  URINALYSIS\"}}], \"clinicalEncounterId\": 142}"'),
('615','488','"{\"complexity\": \"low\", \"Codes\": [{\"conf\": 0.9984004807623814, \"name\": \"87880\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"/ Plan 1. Pain in throat R07.0: Pain in throat  RAPID STREP GROUP A, THROAT  Mucinex DM 30 mg-600 mg tablet,extended release 12 hr -  Take 1 tablet(s)\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9996164227094804, \"name\": \"R070\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"oral route. Â  Â  Qty: 1 blist pack(s) of 20 Â  Â  Refills: 0 Â  Â  Pharmacy: CALEDONIA PHARMACY   RAPID STREP GROUP A, THROAT  Result:   -  Strep: negative Return to Office Patient will return to the office\"}}], \"clinicalEncounterId\": 59}"'),
('899','1102','"{\"complexity\": \"low\", \"Codes\": [{\"conf\": 0.9968579484449694, \"name\": \"81002\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Procedure code: 58120  VAGINAL BLEEDING AFTER MENOPAUSE: CARE INSTRUCTIONS  SURGICAL PATHOLOGY STUDY  URINALYSIS, DIPSTICK  URINALYSIS, DIPSTICK  Results:   -  Blood: Negative  -  Ketone: Negative  -  Protein: Negative  -  Leukocytes: Negative  -  Nitrite\"}}], \"clinicalEncounterId\": 146}"'),
('90123','8921','"{\"complexity\": \"medium\", \"Codes\": [{\"conf\": 0.9990972753776355, \"name\": \"J1100\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/dl/dt/dd/p\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_ProcedureDocumentation\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"the epidural space and ensure there is no vascular uptake. A 3cc mixture of 20 mg of Dexamethasone (2 cc) and 0.5 % lidocaine (1.5 cc) was injected into the epidural space\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9988667373822541, \"name\": \"20610\", \"type\": \"CPT\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/dl/dt/dd/p\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_ProcedureDocumentation\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"0.5 % lidocaine (1.5 cc) was injected into the epidural space.  The needle was removed and the puncture site covered with a Band-Aid. The patient was given post-procedural\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9996237289435855, \"name\": \"M5416\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"2. Degeneration of cervical intervertebral disc M50.30: Other cervical disc degeneration, unspecified cervical region  3. Lumbar radiculopathy M54.16: Radiculopathy, lumbar region  4. Degeneration of lumbar intervertebral disc M51.\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9997789864183196, \"name\": \"M5136\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Other cervical disc degeneration, unspecified cervical region  3. Lumbar radiculopathy M54.16: Radiculopathy, lumbar region  4. Degeneration of lumbar intervertebral disc M51.36: Other intervertebral disc degeneration, lumbar region  Discussion Notes Cervical\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9999342438930537, \"name\": \"M5412\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Assessment / Plan 1. Cervical radiculopathy M54.12: Radiculopathy, cervical region  hydrocodone 5 mg-acetaminophen 325 mg tablet -\"}}, {\"conf\": 0.9999311996288434, \"name\": \"M5030\", \"type\": \"ICD-10-CM\", \"xpath\": \"/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]\", \"section\": \"FROZENSECTIONHTML_AssessmentPlan\", \"extra_info\": {\"summary_ctxt_1\": \"Authorization: Medicare-VA (Medicare) | NOTREQUIRED | Not Required for 62320, 62321  2. Degeneration of cervical intervertebral disc M50.30: Other cervical disc degeneration, unspecified cervical region  3\"}}], \"clinicalEncounterId\": 52}"')

**Output table**
create table ##output
(ctextid int,
vbillid int,
complexity varchar(40),
CPTcode varchar(100000),
diagnosiscode varchar(100000))

insert into ##output values
('7812','1012','low','87635','Z20828,U071'),
('899','189','low','81002','N760'),
('615','488','low','87880','R070'),
('899','1102','low','81002',''),
('90123','8921','medium','J1100,20610','M5416,M5136,M5412,M5030')
```

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Could you be more specific around `CPTcode` and `diagnosiscode`?  The values all appear to be located in an attribute called `name` in the contained array, but it is difficult to determine the rules for what goes where with more details.  Also, is there something you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: @MikeWalton: So all the codes are present under Codes (Within that name and type are the attribute values to be extracted)...The type is CPT and ICD-10 tied to a name ...So all the codes with type CPT should be grouped by commas and all the codes with type ICD-10 should be grouped by commas seperately...I will post the query that I tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this is all showing as invalid JSON when I try to create a test table with your code.  However, looking at the JSON, it appears you have a nested array. So you would need to look into FLATTEN: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Something like this would get you the list of codes with their name and type, from there you can filter on type.

```
select f.value:type, f.value:name
FROM ##input p,
       lateral flatten(input => data, path => 'Codes') f
```

Comment: Hi @Brandon Coleman, I am getting an empty result  when I try to apply the above code

Comment: The path shouldn't be 'Codes' but rather `p.data:Codes`

Comment: After doing that I am getting invalid type [VARIANT] for parameter 'path'

Comment: Any help on this thread would be appreciated!

Comment: That would mean the JSON that you have in that field is not valid.  Would need to do some clean up on the JSON before flatten or other commands would work